# Serve Drupal from Site Root

Tags: drupal-7

I've researching this for over a month now and I'm very frustrated. What I want to do seems very doable but I'm frustrated that there doesn't seem to be one simple answer to this issue.

I've installed Drupal on a domain on a Virtual Private Server. The software is installed by the hosting service using Plesk but they don't support the software or Drupal, so I'm on my own.

When Plesk installs Drupal, it does so in a 'drupal' folder so when you navigate to the site, it says `http://domainname.com/drupal` But I want Drupal to run the entire site from the root. I don't want "drupal" to appear anywhere.

The answers I've seen say that you need to add an .htaccess file that provides a redirect and then to edit the .htaccess file in the Drupal folder and the settings.php file. But when I do this the site throws an error and I can't login to the drupal interface.

I am not a programmer or coder. I've created many HTML sites and even a WordPress site, but WordPress is so much easier to set up this way. So, sorry if this is really a lame question, but I need to know whether I need to re-install drupal in the root folder or if I can get it to actually serve drupal from the root by editing these files.

I'm able to access the site via SSH and edit or create any file needed.

Here are my questions:

1. Can I get Drupal to run from the root by simply editing the drupal/.htaccess file, the settings.php file and by adding an .htaccess file in the site root? If not, what do I need to do?
2. Do I need to move the drupal index.php file to the site root or create a new index file? None of the instructions say anything about this.
3. After editing those files and creating a new .htaccess file will I be able to login and manage the site properly?

Does anyone have a link to a set of instructions for a complete drupal novice? Any help in this endeavor would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, I've already read the other links on StackOverflow on this topic. I've tried the suggestions and still can't get it to work properly.

Comment: have you tried to move all drupal files into root directory?

Comment: That is one of my questions. But, in one of the various posts I read, it said that you can't just move the installation. I don't want to move the files and screw it up even worse

Comment: do backup and move it, after all reconfigure base folder, check /sites/settings.php and you'r done. Something go wrong? Restore backup

Comment: OK. I will try that.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, it appear that with older versions, copy and paste didn't work, so far I was able to login without any issues with @Daimos advice. Did't actually change anything under sites/settings.php. Maybe you should put that as an answer.

Comment: FYI, I gave up trying to move the existing account. I found it easier to simply scrap that installation and reinstall it via my server into the root. I found the custom install option and was able to specify where to install Drupal.